# how to change image dimension for mapped image(i.e image map used image) in html.

Tags: html, imagemap

I have a html file and the html file has only image map data and the image. 
the dimension of the image is 3000 * 3000 . when I am opening the html file the picture is not fully visible because of its size. now the image tag is like bellow:

```
<IMG SRC="test.png" ALT="Site map" USEMAP="#testmap">
```

in this condition the image map is working properly.

But because of its dimension, I am decreasing its dimension .the example is like bellow

```
<IMG SRC="test.png" ALT="Site map" USEMAP="#testmap" width=1000 height=1000>
```

But the image map is not working properly.is their any way to solve the problem.

Comment: How not working properly?

Comment: like A part of the image is linked to a coordinate. But when I am changed the dimension of the image , the position of A is also getting changed .So part A is not responding or not working with respect to the previous coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Actually their is no way to alter the image map coordinates.If your image size is 3000*3000 .then your coordinates are  for that size only.you can't change that directly to 1000*1000.